# format all columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Hi i am looking for a solution how to format all columns or a selection by position (column 0 and 1)

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'value': [20, 10, -5, ],
     'min': [0, 10, -10,],
    'max': [40, 20, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

#df =  df.astype(float).map("{:,.2f} €".format)  # style to €, does not work
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`applymap()` and **f-string** works

```
d = {'value': [20, 10, -5, ],
     'min': [0, 10, -10,],
    'max': [40, 20, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.applymap(lambda x: f"{x:,.2f} €")
```

|  | value | min | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 20.00 € | 0.00 € | 40.00 € |
| 1 | 10.00 € | 10.00 € | 20.00 € |
| 2 | -5.00 € | -10.00 € | 0.00 € |

Answer (score 3):

Just use `astype()` method and chain `applymap()` method to it:-

```
df=df.astype(float).applymap('{:,.2f} €'.format)
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your expected output:-

```
    value       min          max
0   20.00 €     0.00 €      40.00 €
1   10.00 €     10.00 €     20.00 €
2   -5.00 €     -10.00 €    0.00 €
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [dataframe styling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Finer-Control:-Display-Values):

```
df.style.format("{:,.2f} €")
```

[image]

Comment: I do like this solution better. Note to OP that this changes how the data is displayed, not the data itself. You can also save it to excel with this answer.